# What are the arguments to this javascript factory assigned to?

Tags: javascript, factory, anonymous-function

I am trying to understand how this JavaScript pattern works it is an entire library enclosed in parenthesis.  My understanding is that the parenthesis are a way to scope variables, but inside is a single function that takes the argument (global, factory).

I've tried searching for how this pattern works but cannot find anything.

The body of code returns an object that can be used elsewhere, but I don't understand what the purpose of the arguments `global` and `factory` accomplish.

I have been reading about enclosures and anonymous functions, but can't find anything about an enclosure defined like this.

```
(function (global, factory) {
    global.className = factory();
    }  (this, function () {
         ObjectName.prototype = function() {
             /* some code */
         }
         var data = {
              getUsefulData: function(obj) {
                   return new ObjectName(obj, 'usefuldata');
              }
         }
        return data;
    })
);
```

Questions:

- what would happen if the outer function had no arguments?
- what value gets assigned here to the global and variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing, is an [IIFE (an Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) with two parameters. Consider this example:

```
const x = (function(a, b) { return a + b; })(5, 6); // x === 11
```

The parameter `global` gets assigned the argument of `this` (which, when used at the top level, is a universal way of reaching the [global object, `window` for browsers and `global` for Node.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object)), the second parameter `factory` gets assigned the big (second) function.

The IIFE then puts the result of the `factory` function (which is actually the library code) onto the global object under the `className` key (also known as a namespace in this pattern).

---

This is a variation on the [Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript), only what's returned from the `factory` function will be placed on `global.className`, allowing you to have "private" variables and functions that will not be exposed, but are still accessible to the "public" objects.

```
(function(global, factory) {
  global.myModule = factory();
}(this, function() {
  const privateMessage = 'secret';
  function secret() {
    return privateMessage;
  }

  function open() {
    return 'Message: ' + secret();
  }

  return { open };
}));

window.myModule.open(); // Message: secret
// no way to directly access privateMessage or secret().
```

Comment: @r3wt You'll notice that production-facing library code (i.e. after build) has a similar pattern which is a bit more involved (a.k.a. UMD), which allows it to be used both under a global name and with CommonJS/AMD module libraries. This still happens today, it's just not common in *source* code, only in *target* code :)

Comment: well yeah, i know that. i'm talking about writing it out by hand like this.

Comment: I wonder why this structure works (it does, at least in Chrome) despite of the unusual parenthesis pattern (classical: `(function(){}) ()` vs. this one: `( function(){}() )`)?

Comment: @tevemadar That's because the only use the parens have is to make the parser understand that this is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), and not a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), as such, even the more bizarre `!function(){}()` or `+function(){}()` work to the same effect. It's just nicer to use parens for this :)

Comment: The preferred way to get a global object today (in modern environments is `globalThis` which works everywhere

Comment: Wow - great explanation.  My head is exploding as I work through this.  I didn't get that the second function was an argument for the first, and the return allows making some functions public.  Now I need to read *essentialjsdesignpatters*.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Unfortunately, in almost every case today, `this` is still more likely to work, as it works in non-modern environments too. But I suppose it's trivial to polyfill regardless.